# microsoft navision 2009, how to get the last nine characters

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision

I have a string like this: Nl41ingb0006618174

And I want to return only the last nine characters.

I try it like this:

```
MyString := (IBAN);
MyString2.GETSUBTEXT(MyString, 1,TextPos-9);
MESSAGE(FORMAT(MyString2));
```

> where IBAN = bank account number

```
MyString2 = bigtext

MyString = Text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it via COPYSTR + STRLEN:

```
IF STRLEN(MyString) >= 9 THEN
  MyString2 := COPYSTR(MyString,STRLEN(MyString)-8,9);
```